Trying to connect springboot application database with AWS RDS
I have a springboot application which runs locally perfectly. But I am trying to connect AWS RDS postgres from my springboot application with a free tier account. RDS Postgres is publicly accessible. Even I tried following YouTube tutorials and doing it the it the same way but it didn't work.
WORKING - for local environment
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5442/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

NOT WORKING - with configured RDS while running app
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://product-service.***********.amazonaws.com:5442/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

Error I'm getting while running springboot application
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/validation/ValidationException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3572) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:2237) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.findConstructor(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:405) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.forClass(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:394) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:227) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.loadFailureAnalyzers(FailureAnalyzers.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:61) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:55) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.instantiate(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:382) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:228) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:160) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:483) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExceptionReporters(SpringApplication.java:831) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:814) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at com.example.productservice.ProductServiceApplication.main(ProductServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.validation.ValidationException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted

2024-09-08T20:58:37.684+05:30 TRACE 23573 --- [ProductService] [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers    : Unable to instantiate factory class [org.springframework.boot.liquibase.LiquibaseChangelogMissingFailureAnalyzer] for factory type [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/exception/ChangeLogParseException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3572) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:2237) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.findConstructor(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:405) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.forClass(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:394) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:227) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.loadFailureAnalyzers(FailureAnalyzers.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:61) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:55) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.instantiate(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:382) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:228) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:160) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:483) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExceptionReporters(SpringApplication.java:831) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:814) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at com.example.productservice.ProductServiceApplication.main(ProductServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted

2024-09-08T20:58:37.696+05:30 TRACE 23573 --- [ProductService] [  restartedMain] o.s.c.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader   : Loaded [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalysisReporter] names: [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter]
2024-09-08T20:58:37.697+05:30 ERROR 23573 --- [ProductService] [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [The connection attempt failed.] [n/a]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at com.example.productservice.ProductServiceApplication.main(ProductServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [The connection attempt failed.] [n/a]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [The connection attempt failed.] [n/a]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ExtractionContext.getQueryResults(ExtractionContext.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1429) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:358) ~[postgresql-42.7.2.jar:42.7.2]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.7.2.jar:42.7.2]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:273) ~[postgresql-42.7.2.jar:42.7.2]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:446) ~[postgresql-42.7.2.jar:42.7.2]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:298) ~[postgresql-42.7.2.jar:42.7.2]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:137) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:360) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:461) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:550) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:98) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:111) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:592) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:752) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243) ~[postgresql-42.7.2.jar:42.7.2]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.7.2.jar:42.7.2]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136) ~[postgresql-42.7.2.jar:42.7.2]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262) ~[postgresql-42.7.2.jar:42.7.2]
    ... 56 common frames omitted

Need help to solve this. Thanks in advance

You'll have to make sure the application has a public route to the internet to connect to RDS's public IP address, and that the outbound IP of the application is allowed in the security group of the RDS instance.

Looks like you are missing a lot of dependencies in your POM file.

"While running app..." from where ? from your laptop to RDS ? from EC2 ? and as smac2020 mentioned the logs shows several dependencies are missing.

I got the solution after searching everywhere and watching videos.
I added security-group-rule with the below configuration, and it is now working perfectly fine.
PROTOCOL   PORT   SOURCE
TCP        5432   0.0.0.0/0

